Formulating a general formula for a game called FLAMES with n digits and k number of elements.
This question is related to this game called FLAMES.
Basically, take two names and cancel out the letters which are in both the names. For example, take Bob and Blake. The B's cancel out to give o and lake. Now, count the letters remaining to get 1+4= 5.
Bob, Blake =5 Bob, Alice =8 are two cases we will consider.
The game is sort of iterative in nature.. basically, you count the letters in FLAMES till you reach the desired number if the number is lesser than 6. le
In FLAMES, E would be removed first for the first case of Bob and Blake to give FLAMS. In the second case, 8>6 so the counting repeats from start and L from FLAMES is removed to give FAMES. This process is repeated till only one letter is left.
For first case: FLAMES-FLAMS-FLAM-LAM-LM-M.
For second case: FLAMES-FAMES-FAES-FAE-FE-F.
For the case with only 1: FLAMES-LAMES-AMES-MES-ES-S.
Now, let's abstract the FLAMES to a list or a set.
S(n)= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....,n}
Let's represent the case of Bob and Blake as 5→S(6) or S(5;6).
Is there any way to generalize
1.2 S(n) or S(2;n)

n→S(6) or S(n;6)

n→S(n) or S(n;n)

n→S(k) or S(n;k)


